# How to make data stored in Shared Preferences available across sessions in Android

Tags: android

I have data which I store in shared preferences. When I close and re-open the app the data still appears in the Share Preferences file, however it is not retrievable.  I can re-submit the data from SettingsActivity file (my file I use to upload the data to Shared Preferences) which makes the data retievable by other Activity files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes once `Shared Preferences` is saved you can get them whenever you want in the app. It will be only deleted when it the `Shared Preferences` is removed or app cache is cleared.

Please elaborate what do you mean by

> however it is not retrievable.

This is how I use shared preference using kotlin.

To Save:

```
val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext)
pref.edit().putString("key" , "value").apply()
```

To get:

```
val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext)
pref.getString("key", "")
```

Comment: I am using Java.                              SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DiscountType", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            discountTypeSTR = sharePreferences.getString("discount", "");.

Comment: SharePreferences works properly until I close and re-open the application.  The problem is created when the app is re-launched.  The data is still present in the xml file in the sharedPreferences folder, however it cannot be used.